# Cmd Window Not Displaying

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, task

On a Win 8 machine, I have a batch file that does a dump of a MySQL database. It has a pause cmd at the end so I can see how the dump went.

It is run as a Scheduled Task daily. For some reason I'm having problems with it over the last week:

1. When the Scheduled Task runs, the Cmd Window is not visible, and does not display on the Task Bar (I'm using Classic Shell). It displays OK if I manually run the batch file.
2. Whilst I can see the process 'Windows Command Processor' in Task Manager, I cannot find a way to 'switch' to it.

Any ideas pls?

Comment: Scheduled tasks may have a setting to `interact with the desktop`

Comment: In the Task properties, General tab, there is a checkbox 'Hidden'. However, I have not checked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible anymore:

`services are run on a different desktop than users, and this affects the Task Scheduler as well.`

[More info is here -](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Sunny. Your comment and link helped me to identify and resolve the issues:

Comment: In the Task properties, I had changed the Security options from 'Run only when user logged in', to 'Run whether user logged in or not'.

'Run whether user logged in or not' runs the Task in Session(0). Thus, not only was it 'hidden' from me - presumably in Session(1), Task Manager listed the process under Background Processes, and 'switching' to it was not possible.

I reverted to 'Run only when user logged in', and voila! The Cmd Window is again visible when the batch file is run, AND, in Task Manager, it is now listed under the 'Apps' section, where I CAN 'switch' to it.